# What type of analysis will help discover common attributes of collections of items?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, factor-analysis

Suppose the following situation. You have a list of food items: bottles of milk, ham pieces, eggs, bananas etc. You also have bags of food, where a bag might contain, e.g. 3 bottles of milk, 5 pieces of ham, 6 eggs and 1 banana i.e. multiple instances of the same item are allowed in a bag. You also have a way to know how "good" such of selection of food is. For example, you know what percentage of people packing a bag of that exact content survived on a deserted island for a week.

However, even though you know what selection of food is good, you do not know what makes it good, and this is exactly what you want to find out. Is it banana-to-ham-pieces ratio? Is it the number of eggs that makes it successful?

How would you approach such a problem? Is factor analysis maybe the way to go?

Comment: Do you have the function that returns the "quality" of the selection, or are you estimating that too? If you know it, why don't you just optimize over the input variables (food items)? If linearity is assumed (multiplying all the inputs by a fixed quantity multiplies the output by the same), you can constrain the budget; only consider selections of up to a fixed number of items, etc.

Comment: I can not immediately know the "quaility" of a newly composed selection. I only know it for a pre-existing list of selections, sort of a training set. So you could say I'm trying to discover archetypes within the existing selections, e.g. bags with a lot of eggs and bananas seem to be doing well, but also bags that have milk and ham in a 3:1 ratio.

Answer (score 2):

So the challenge is essentially estimating the quality from the food items. What you have is a regression problem. If the quality can be expressed as a percentage (i.e., it is bounded), you can use a logistic model, $Q(\mathbf x; \mathbf w) = 1/\left( 1+\exp(-\mathbf w \cdot \mathbf x) \right)$, and minimize the squared error loss:

$\mathbf w^* = \arg \max_w \sum_i \| Q(\mathbf x_i; w) - q_i \|^2$, where $q_i$ is the quality of bag $i$, and $\mathbf x_i$ is the list of items in bag $i$. You can also add a regularization term to this objective.

The weight vector $\mathbf w$ will tell you the relative contribution of each item towards the quality.